# Proving That a Polynomial with distinct roots has no common roots with its derivative.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots

> Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and has $n$ distinct roots.
>
> Prove that $P(x)$ has no roots in common with $P'(x)$.

What I've tried so far:
Suppose that $r\in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $P(x)$ that means that,

$$P(x) = \space (x-r)\cdot Q(x)$$

Where, $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. And differentiating both sides gives,

$$P'(x) = Q(x) \space + \space (x-r)\cdot Q'(x)$$

Setting $x=r$ results in,

$$P'(r) = Q(r)\ne0$$

And we know that $Q(r)\ne0$ because $Q(x)$ contains all the roots of $P(x)$ except $r$ therefore it wouldn't be equalt to zero at $x=r$. This process can then be applied to the rest of the roots of $P(x)$.

What could I add/remove to improve this proof? Should I try another approach? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your proof is fine.  Another approach might be to consider the function curve for $ \ P(x) \ : \ \ $  if all of its zeroes are distinct, then the $ \ (r_i \ , \ 0) \ $ are all "crossing" intercepts (since they have multiplicity 1), so the "slope" of the curve at each of these intercepts is non-zero, i.e., $ \ P'(r_i) \ \neq \ 0 \ \ . $

Comment: A more coherent explanation of why $Q(r)\ne0$: If $Q(r)=0$ then $P$ has a multiple root at $r$.

Comment: It is fine. But you do not need to apply your process to the other roots since $r$ was an arbitrary root.